# Zend_Controller_Request_Http::getQuery returns NULL

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is the URL I am using:

```
http://my-zend-application.example/api/amenity/index/id/1
```

Which basically points to:

```
module => api
controller => amenity
action => index
id => 1
```

But when I do:

```
var_dump($_GET, $request->getQuery('id'));
```

I get an empty array and NULL. Shouldn't the id parameter in the URL be inside the $_GET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the query string - the part of the url after the ?  - really is empty, as the `$_GET` correctly reports.

If you wish to get the value of the `id` parameter, you need `$request->getParam('id')`.